# What do terms half-rate and quarter-rate mean for DRAM memory controllers?

Tags: terminology, controller, ddr3

DDR3 Memory controller are often presented as being half rate or quarter rate, but what does this mean? e.g if I have a DDR3 SDRAM that is x16, what does the half or quarter rate imply in that case and why do we need to create such memory controllers?

Answer (score 1):

From Altera's [Using High-Performance DDR, DDR2, and DDR3 SDRAM With SOPC Builder](https://www.intel.co.jp/content/dam/altera-www/global/ja_JP/pdfs/literature/an/an517.pdf):

> Full- or half-rate SDRAM high-performance controllers have the
> following definitions:
>
> - Full-rate controllers present data to the local interface at twice the width of the actual SDRAM interface at the full SDRAM clock rate.
> - Half-rate controllers present data to the local interface at four times the width of the actual SDRAM interface at half the SDRAM clock
>   rate.
>
> Implementing the SDRAM high-performance controllers in half-rate mode
> gives the highest possible SDRAM clock frequency while allowing the
> more complex core logic to operate at half this frequency.

Basically, half-rate (and by extension, quarter-rate) application interfaces allow the SDRAM clock to be faster relative to your internal system clock. This improves both bandwidth and latency.